# Push Notification does show new records in the Console list view

Tags: service-cloud-console, console, push-notification

I have configured the push notification for cases for few fields such as Status, Priority & Subject, however the list row does not highlight new records. Is there a way to configure the Push notification to show new cases dynamically in the view?

Answer (score 0):

This is working as designed when using the standard Push Notification functionality. If you want to refresh list views when new records are created you need to roll your own notifications using the Streaming API.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000199167